# how to create a range of values and then use them to insert data into postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

**Background Information:**

I need to auto generate a bunch of records in a table.  The only piece of information I have is a start range and an end range. 
Let's say my table looks like this:

```
     id 
     widgetnumber
```

The logic needs to be contained within a .sql file.
I'm running postgresql

**Code**

This is what I have so far... as a test... and it seems to be working:

```
DO $$
DECLARE widgetnum text;
BEGIN
    SELECT 5 INTO widgetnum;

    INSERT INTO widgets VALUES(DEFAULT, widgetnum);
END $$;
```

And then to run it, I do this from a command line on my database server:

```
testbox:/tmp# psql -U myuser -d widgets -f addwidgets.sql 
DO
```

**Questions**

1. How would I modify this code to loop through a range of widget numbers and insert them all? 
   for example, I would be provided with a start range and an end range (100 to 150 let's say)
2. Can you point me to a good online resource to learn the syntax i should be using?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the DO block? Your example can be simplified to a single `insert into widgets (widgetnumber) values (5);`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *How would I modify this code to loop through a range of widget numbers and insert them all?*

You can use [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) for that.

```
insert into widgets (widgetnumber)
select i
from generate_series(100, 150) as t(i);
```

> *Can you point me to a good online resource to learn the syntax i should be using?*

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html

Comment: how do i handle the "DEFAULT" value that autogenerates the pk?

Comment: and do i still need to declare the variable widgetnumber?

Comment: If you omit the id column from your insert (as the suggested generate series command does) then any DEFAULT values will be automatically handled by the database.

Comment: you don't need plpgsql at all, just use the generate_series command in straight sql.

Comment: xzilla, i see.  but i still want to know the answer about how to insert another value before the "i" variable ... because I have to populate a few other tables in similar way.  But I guess it's best to just ask another question.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
dvdrental=# \d test
                       Table "public.test"
 Column |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer                |           |          |
 name   | character varying(250) |           |          |

dvdrental=# begin;
BEGIN
dvdrental=# insert into test(id,name) select generate_series(1,100000),'Kishore';
INSERT 0 100000
```